# tab<->window component?

Tags: c#, winforms

I wonder if there is out of the box winforms UI widget that can be draged out from container (like google chrome  tab) into new same container window (to be joined with other such tabs in future if needed). All in all I wonder if there is flexible tab<->window component? If there is none I wonder if there is one under liberal opensource license?

Comment: You can make D+D do anything you like with simple code.  Just write event handlers for the DragEnter and the DragDrop events.  Why you need a component and what it should do is very unclear.